# It runs, but there is a yellow underline saying 'dead code'. What's wrong?

Tags: eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nzPf.png)

It runs, but there is a yellow underline saying 'dead code'. What's wrong?

```
public class OperEx03 {
//논리연산자
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("true && false : " + (true&&false)); //모두가 참(true)일때만 참(true)반환
    System.out.println("false && false : " + (false&&false));
    System.out.println("true && true : " + (true&&true));
    System.out.println("================================");
    System.out.println("true || false : " + (true || false)); //둘 중 하나라도 참(true)이라면 참(true)반환
    System.out.println("true || true : " + (true||true));
    System.out.println("false || false : " + (false||false));
}
```

}

Comment: The second false is never evaluated, since the first false is false. False && ?? is false in boolean tests. You may want to google "boolean short circuit evaluation" for more info.

Comment: explainer. thank you

Comment: Yes, you have the same situation in the `true || false` and `true || true` evaluations. Once the first `true` is evaluated, the other half can be ignored and never gets evaluated, because true || ?? is always true no matter what the other side is.

Comment: It compiles normally, but I was curious about the yellow underline. thank you

Comment: Yellow means warning, not error, and [_dead code_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code) means here [_unreachable code_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreachable_code).

Comment: Eclipse is just warning you that there is code that is not needed and will never be executed (it is "dead"). It is possible to turn off the warning but usually it is a good idea to take notice of the warning.